# Difference between two rows in MySQL Workbench, but LAG is not authorized

Tags: mysql, window-functions

I have a dataset as in this example :

```
id | product_id  |        date       |  weight
1  |    454      |2019-06-26 16:08:45|   900
2  |    454      |2019-06-27 13:24:16|   900
3  |    454      |2019-06-28 10:53:42|   899
4  |    352      |2018-04-18 10:53:42|   124
5  |    352      |2018-04-19 15:26:51|   124
6  |    112      |2019-12-08 11:44:01|   065
7  |    375      |2020-03-15 08:23:43|   483
8  |    375      |2020-03-15 18:07:33|   496
9  |    375      |2020-03-16 14:32:24|   496
```

And I would like to get only the rows that have a weight different from the previous one or different from the next one. In the case of the example the expected output is :

```
id | product_id  |        date       |  weight
2  |    454      |2019-06-27 13:24:16|   900
3  |    454      |2019-06-28 10:53:42|   899
7  |    375      |2020-03-15 08:23:43|   483
8  |    375      |2020-03-15 18:07:33|   496
```

However, I have only reading permissions on this database, so the `LAG()` function does not work. What other options do I have?

Comment: Are you using the MySQL version that  supports  window functions?

Comment: What is the output from `SELECT version();` from within MySQL Workbench?

Comment: @mustaccio I think I can't use window functions such as lag or lead... di you have any specific functino in mind?

Comment: @Vérace the output is 5.7.24

Comment: I would **strongly advise** you to upgrade to version 8 of MySQL - Oracle/MySQL have added a shedload of really really useful functionality recently (`CHECK` constraints, Common Table Expressions, Window functions, JSON). You really are missing out by using 5.7! MySQL 8 is now at version 20, time enough for any (ahem...) issues with the new functionality to have been (largely) ironed out! Window functions are **made** for this sort of problem.

Comment: Also, could you provide your table structures as DDL and your data as DML (also as a [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=c802a8a50bf92742903824ade3d95eba))? This eliminates duplication of effort on the part of those who wish to assist you and reduces the chance of error ([SSOT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_source_of_truth)). Help us to help you! BTW, welcome to the forum!

Comment: There are lots of Q&A in stackoverflow that discuss the simulation of LAG() and LEAD().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT id
    ,product_id 
    ,date
    ,weight
FROM
(
SELECT t.id
    ,t.product_id 
    ,t.date
    ,t.weight
    ,(SELECT weight FROM table WHERE product_id = t.product_id  AND date < t.date ORDER BY date LIMIT 1) AS prev_weight
    ,(SELECT weight FROM table WHERE product_id = t.product_id  AND date > t.date ORDER BY date LIMIT 1) AS next_weight
FROM table AS t 
) AS t1
WHERE weight <> prev_weight OR weight <> next_weight
```

Comment: I ended up doing something very similar to this, but I didn't use ORDER BY, because it is too expensive to a large database.

Comment: @LucasMatosMolter you may receive incorrect results without ORDER BY. But you can use appropriate index (on product_id, date) to improve the performance. Also you can probably use ORDER BY id (if id has the same order as date and it is a primary key and you use inndodb then index on product_id will already be sorted in a way you need).

Answer (score 0):

```
set @tmp:=-1; set @vari:= 0; set @prodtmp:=-1;
select id,
    product_id,
    date,
    weight,
    if(@prodtmp=-1,@prodtmp:= product_id,if(@prodtmp=product_id,1,@tmp:=-1)) as sameProduct,
    @prodtmp:=prod_id as prod,
    if(@tmp=-1,0,@vari:=weight-@tmp) as temporary,
    @tmp:= weight as dummy,
    @vari as variation
from creditquote
where weight is not null
order by product_id asc, date asc;
```

What I still cannot do is hodding the rows where the variation is 0, if someone knows how to do it please let me know.

Answer (score -1):

I will add another answer, leaving the comments on my previous answer for what they are...

A tested answer is:

```
select id, product_id, date, weight, previous, next from (
  select 
    d.id,
    d.product_id,
    d.date,
    d.weight,
    (select d1.weight from dataset d1 where d1.product_id=d.product_id and d1.date<d.date and d1.weight<>d.weight order by d1.date desc limit 1) "PREVIOUS",
    (select d1.weight from dataset d1 where d1.product_id=d.product_id and d1.date>d.date and d1.weight<>d.weight order by d1.date asc limit 1) "NEXT"
  from dataset d
) x
where PREVIOUS is not null
  or NEXT is not null
;
```

output:

```
id  product_id  date                weight  previous    next
1   454         2019-06-26 16:08:45 900                899
2   454         2019-06-27 13:24:16 900                899
3   454         2019-06-28 10:53:00 899     900 
7   375         2020-03-15 08:23:00 483                496
8   375         2020-03-15 18:07:00 496     483 
9   375         2020-03-16 13:32:00 496     483
```

I have two more results than the 'expected output'.  But i think they are within the description of the 'desired output' (see columns previous and/or next), which states " have a weight different from the previous one or different from the next one."

This query was tested here: [DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=7accd5a73f63ff782c8959b033e1a1f2)

Answer (score -2):

```
select 
    d.id, 
    d.product_id, 
    d.date, 
    d.weight,
    d2.weigth "PREVIOUS WEIGHT",
    d3.weigth "NEXT WEIGHT"
from dataset d
cross join (
    select weight 
    from dataset dp 
    where dp.product_id=d.product_id and dp.date<d.date
    order by dp.date desc
    limit 1
      ) d2
cross join (
    select weight 
    from dataset dp 
    where dp.product_id=d.product_id and dp.date>d.date
    order by dp.date asc
    limit 1
      ) d3
```

Comment: I doubt that this is valid syntax.

Comment: Thank you! It seems like a very good idea, however, I don't know why it say "Unknown column 'd.product_id' in 'where clause' ". Do you have aby guess about the mistake I am making?

Comment: Actualy, I did it! Thank you!!!!

Comment: Just a small change...
select 
    d.id, 
    d.product_id, 
    d.date, 
    d.weight,
    d2.weigth "PREVIOUS WEIGHT",
    d3.weigth "NEXT WEIGHT"
from dataset d
cross join (
    select dp.weight 
    from dataset dp, dataset d 
    where dp.product_id=d.product_id and dp.date<d.date
    order by dp.date desc
    limit 1
      ) d2
cross join (
    select dp.weight 
    from dataset dp, dataset d 
    where dp.product_id=d.product_id and dp.date>d.date
    order by dp.date asc
    limit 1
      ) d3

Comment: I tried to vote for your answer but my reputation is too small..

Comment: I think that you can upvote and/or mark as correct your own questions regardless of your reputation - it's other questions that you won't be able to upvote until your rep is x (x = 50?). You may have to wait 24 hrs (or whatever period) before upvoting and/or marking as correct - AFAIK?

Comment: This query is not a correct answer to the question. It does NOT provide previous and next weights

Comment: you need at least 10 Rep to upvote, that is why the user who answers usually upvotes rep 1 users

Comment: Does this query work in MySQL? dataset d should not be visible inside d2 without a LATERAL join?

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ you were right, at first I had the impression that it woked, but I double checked this morning and I realised that it does not provide the correct answer. Do you hvae any idea about what I should change?

Comment: I will have a look at why my query gives an error later today....

Comment: OK, my answer was **wrong**, and i still wrong.  Thanks for all the downvoters who did not even place a correct working answer, very brave of you!